# Drawing arrows above nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am trying to create the following diagram with TikZ:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to create anything else but the text.

The code I have so far produces nothing but the text. I haven't been able to find a way of generating any arrows the way I want them:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0, 1) -- (2, 1);
    \node[draw] at (0, 0) {\ttfamily 01101100};
    \node[draw] at (2, 0) {\ttfamily 00011110};
    \node[draw] at (4, 0) {\ttfamily 10111100};
    \node[draw] at (6, 0) {\ttfamily 00000000};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Note** that there has been an arrow attempt but the result has nothing to do with what I want; also, the nodes I have have a rectangular bounding box around them.

Comment: Please post the code of what you have so far.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I know the rule, I should have posted in the first place, but there is nothing even close to what I need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<-, very thick] (0,0) -- ++(1.7,0)  node [midway, below] {01101100} node [midway, above] {\scriptsize bit order}; 
\draw [<-, very thick] (2,0) -- ++(1.7,0)  node [midway, below] {00011110}; 
\draw [<-, very thick] (4,0) -- ++(1.7,0)  node [midway, below] {10111100}; 
\draw [<-, very thick] (6,0) -- ++(1.7,0)  node [midway, below] {00000000}; 
\draw [->, very thick] (0,0.5) -- (7.7,0.5)  node [midway, above] {\scriptsize byte order};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Modified solution according to [Marian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/153812/marian-g)'s suggestion:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<-, very thick] (0,0) node (start) {} -- ++(1.7,0) node [midway, below] {\ttfamily 01101100} node [midway, above] {\scriptsize bit order}; 
\draw [<-, very thick] (2,0) -- ++(1.7,0) node [midway, below] {\ttfamily 00011110}; 
\draw [<-, very thick] (4,0) -- ++(1.7,0) node [midway, below] {\ttfamily 10111100}; 
\draw [<-, very thick] (6,0) -- ++(1.7,0) node (end) {} node [midway, below] {\ttfamily 00000000}; 
\draw [->, very thick] ($(start) + (0,0.5)$) -- ($(end) + (0,0.5)$) node [midway, above] {\scriptsize byte order};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1); Suggestion: The coordinates in the last `\draw` command are calculated by hand. This can be avoided if you name the previous nodes (the first and last one) and use them for drawing the long arrow.

Comment: Oh seems so easy when I see it! I tried it and it works! I am accepting your answer and then I'll start reading more so I understand everything you wrote here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun: with a matrix.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,inner sep=0pt,nodes={font=\ttfamily,inner sep=1pt},column sep=1em] (mat)
   { 01101100 & 00011110 & 10111100 &  00000000 \\
   };
   \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
   {\draw[-latex,thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]mat-1-\X.north east) -- 
    ([yshift=0.5ex]mat-1-\X.north west)
    \ifnum\X=1
     node[midway,above] {bit order}
    \fi;}
 \end{scope}  
 \draw[-latex,thick] ([yshift=1ex]A.north west) -- 
    ([yshift=1ex]A.north east) node[midway,above] {byte order};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]